# Poster authorship

Tags: conference, etiquette, poster

I've been working on a research paper for about a year now, and am the first author (a graduate student). I'm getting a lot of help from some faculty mentors, and they will be listed as 2nd and 3rd authors if the paper gets published. 
Before submitting the article to publication, I'm planning to present the work at a conference. Should my faculty mentors also be listed as coauthors on the poster, or is there no need? I have no problem putting them on it, but do not have enough time to communicate with them about this before the poster is due. What should I do? Do all paper authors have to be poster authors as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I think that you *do* need to communicate with them. They are the ones who can answer your question, not the people here. They may prefer that you do it alone and they may prefer to be included. If you just choose one without asking *them* you could wind up being wrong.

If you are concerned that they might not respond in time, you can make a proposal and ask for feedback by a certain time or you will go forward with it. The proposal could be either for sole or for joint authorship. Say what you propose to do and say that you will go forward unless you get a negative response by (some date/time).

Comment: good idea! wish i thought of it first. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you present joint work, you should list all the participants. But you should also let your co-authors know about the conference and get their feedback on your poster.